# AngularJS ngTable with server side loading

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I tried to use ngTable with server side sorting and pagination.

The html:

```
   <table ng-table="dataTable" class="table table-striped">
          <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
                    <td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">{{row.name}}
                    </td>
         </tr>
   </table>
```

In the controller :

```
    $scope.dataTable= new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,          
                count: 10,         
                sorting: {
                    name: 'desc'   
                }
            }, {
                counts: [],
                total: 0,
                getData: function($defer, params) {
                    ... httpGet according to the params, server returns just the relevant for selected 
                        page

                }
            });
```

getData function is called in page change, and works fine. but sort is sorting just the page, and not calls getData. can I use this directive to mu need?

Comment: I suggest you to use material table https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Comment: thanks, I prefer to use ngTable , since it is a part of big web application that uses it